# Vagrant network collides with a non-hostonly network

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to get a vagrant box up and running, but I keep getting network collide errors. This box is a fresh download of trusty64. I have been searching every file and folder dealing with vagrant trying to find something specifying an IP I can't. I am running vagrant on a windows 7 machine. Here is my Vagrantfile:

C:\Users\.vagrant\boxes...\Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  # This Vagrantfile is auto-generated by 'vagrant package' to contain
  # the MAC address of the box. Custom configuration should be placed in
  # the actual 'Vagrantfile' in this box.
  config.vm.base_mac = "0800278493DB"
end

# Load include vagrant file if it exists after the auto-generated
# so it can override any of the settings
include_vagrantfile = File.expand_path("../include/_Vagrantfile", __FILE__)
load include_vagrantfile if File.exist?(include_vagrantfile)
```

This is the error I receive from a vagrant up command:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.
```

How do I get the IP on my virtualbox not to collide?

UPDATE

A image of my Vagrantfile

[image: Vagrantfile]

Comment: Show your **whole** `Vagrantfile `.

Comment: No, it isn't. It does not even contain the reference to `trusty64` box you mentioned.

Comment: Please find the image of my Vagrantfile above.

Comment: This is **not** your `Vagrantfile`. It is a piece that is included in the box. Please show the `Vagrantfile` you use to run the machine.

Comment: I don't know of another Vagrantfile. Where would I be located on my windows machine?

Comment: Please read the Vagrant tutorial; starting with the [Project setup](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/project_setup.html).

Comment: line 10 of your Vagrantfile, you include another vagrant, this is where the setting will be .. show the file at `../include/Vagrantfile`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check the IP you have on your LAN connection and make sure no devices are colliding with the IP on your Vagrantfile.

I got this error and I had `192.168.1.2` on my laptop's wifi and I was setting `192.168.1.10` on my Vagrantfile. So I changed the IP on my Vagrantfile to `192.168.2.10` to make sure it won't collide with any device on my network.

Comment: My vagrant machine was acting weird only when I was home. Found out it was sharing my router's IP address. Changing the vagrant IP address fixed the issue.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same challenge, and did the following to solve it:

In VirtualBox, go to File -> Host Network Manager

Take note of the IPv4 address in this window. In your Vagrantfile, use any IP in the reserved private IPv4 network range. Let's say your VirtualBox IPv4 address is 192.168.56.1/24. In your Vagrantfile you could then add

> config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.5"

Remember to configure your *hosts* file accordingly, should that be required.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I was working from home so what I did on my `Vagrantfile` was:

```sh
# app.vm.network :private_network, ip: '10.0.0.07' # work
  app.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.56.77' # home
```

and I comment/uncomment depending on where I am.

Answer (score 1):

What tripped me up was that i wanted public network not private host-only network. So instead of `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.1"` i did `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.1"` and that worked just fine. I had checked there were no ip conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

1.
in homestead.rb find

## Configure A Private Network IP     config.vm.network :private_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.10.10"

because ip is fixed

2.
To set your own ip
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.1.234", :bridge => 'your own IP'

3.
reload box  and choose you are using WIFI
now you can access in the local network

Answer (score 0):

Hot tip! If you're editing the hell out of your config file and nothing is working, double check that you are editing `Homestead.yaml` - NOT `Homestead.yaml.example`

I did it, we all do it, don't look at me like that

Answer (score -2):

I resolve this connection, by disconnecting with internet, then run vagrant up. Once vagrant done its processing so i connect again.

Before this issue, i checked my ip, so it was 10.1 and my homestead is running on 10.10 and i resolved this iss

Comment: This does not fix the issue just a work around, it would be quite painful to do this each time.

Comment: agreed, @ZacGrierson what about if we change ip address from homestead.yml file. this would be quick fix, right?